# Function to match the case of a text as per another text

Tags: c#, performance, strings, google-translate

I am translating a text into another language using Google APIs.

Sometimes the translated text returned from the API does not match the case of the text  provided - e.g. when translating the text "Now Activated" to German, I get the translated text response as "jetzt aktiviert" instead of "Jetzt Aktiviert".

I wrote a function which can change the case of translated text to match the input text:

```
public string MaintainCase(string text, string translatedText)
    {
        // Split the inputs provided into string arrays
        var textStrArray = text.Split(' ');
        var translatedTextStrArray = translatedText.Split(' ');

        // Count the no of words of both the texts provided
        var noOfWordsInText = textStrArray.Length;
        var noOfWordsInTranslatedText = translatedTextStrArray.Length;

        // Check if the word count matches
        bool wordCountMatches =
                        noOfWordsInText == noOfWordsInTranslatedText
                        ? true
                        : false;

        // Start changing the case of translated text as per text
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfWordsInText; i++)
        {
            // Take the word no i of text and translated text
            var textWord = textStrArray[i];
            var translatedTextWord = translatedTextStrArray[i];

            // Using string builder to modify the first character of translated text
            // based on the case identified of the first character of text
            var strBuilder = new StringBuilder(translatedTextWord);
            var changedChar =
                    char.IsUpper(textWord[0])
                    ? char.ToUpper(translatedTextWord[0])
                    : char.ToLower(translatedTextWord[0]);

            strBuilder[0] = changedChar;
            translatedTextStrArray[i] = strBuilder.ToString();

            // If the word count does not match, after changing the case of only first word, break the loop
            if (!wordCountMatches)
            {
                break;
            }
        }

        // Return the modified translated text
        return string.Join(" ", translatedTextStrArray);
    }
```

Kindly suggest if this can be made more efficient (usage of string builders etc) and if I need to add some additional checks which I may have missed.

Comment: Frame challenge: is the result really what we want?  E.g. translating German *mein Buch* to English, we normally want *my book*, not *my Book*.  Similarly, when going the other way, we must respect the capitalisation that the rules of the language demand, rather than slavishly following the source language.

Comment: In the application this can be made optional by providing a default bool parameter 'maintainCase = false'.
However is the code fine for the scenario where we _do_ want to utilize this functionality?

Comment: This looks like trouble to me and as a method that will never be good enough because of all strange possibilities in real world texts. Have you considered the functionality provided by `CultureInfo.TextInfo` for instance `ToTitleCase()` and the like?